# Display the selected item to another component using react hooks

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I have a section in which contains templates, now I want a user to select one of the templates and edit the data in templates eg name, job title, contact etc.

Here is my live demo in code sandbox [editor live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/templates-ifm21?file=/src/Components/Settings.js)

Here is templates.js

```
export default function Templates() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");
  let history = useHistory();

  const handleSelected = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.innerHTML;
    setSelected(value);
   history.push('/Settings') 
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Select one of the Template below by clicking title</h2>

    <div className={`template_one ${selected === "Template_one" ? "selected" : "unselected"}`} onClick={(e) => {setSelected(selected !== "Template_one" ? "Template_one" : ""); handleSelected(e);}}>
        <h1>Template_one</h1>
        <table striped bordered hover size="sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Job</th>
              <th>Facebook</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <th>Developer</th>
              <td>facebook/Mark</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
   
      </div>

      <div className={`template_two  ${selected === "Template_two" ? "selected" : "unselected"}`} onClick={(e) => {setSelected(selected !== "Template_two" ? "Template_two" : "");handleSelected(e);}}>
        <h1>Template_two</h1>

        <table striped bordered hover size="sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Job</th>
              <th>Company</th>
              <th>Contact </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Trump</td>
              <th>President</th>
              <td>Trump Organization</td>
              <td>+1 728 256 345</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is settings.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Settings() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Settings</h1>
      <div className="Settings">
        <form>
          Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" />
          Job: <input type="text" name="job" /> <br /> 
          Facebook: <input type="text" name="facebook" /> 
          Company: <input type="text" name="company" />  
          Contact: <input type="text" name="contact" /> 
        </form>
        <div className="selected-template">
          Here should be the selected template
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Expected result:

[image]

**Problem: I don't know how to display the selected templates in the settings component.**

How do I copy the selected template to the settings component so that the user can edit the selected template.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but someone deleted my other post that's why I'm seeing your message now. If you want to make different styles you can add classnames to your data. Also if you want, you can look at this libary: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/ it is so populer around react users. You can basicly make all styles in javascript with this libary. If you gonna use this libary you can add all jss in your data.
here is example:

```js
  const table1= {
  root: {
  background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
  border: 0,
  borderRadius: 3,
  boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
  color: 'white',
  height: 48,
  padding: '0 30px',
  },
 };
Data=[
  {
  name:'something',
  style:table1
  },
  {
  age:22,
  style:table2
  }
]
```

and basic explanation about how to use this styles

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';



function Table() {
  const classes = props.data.style();
  return <Table className={classes.root}>Your table here</Table>;
}

export default withStyles(props.data.style)(Table);
```

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever why I should keep data in the parent component while I will  have hundreds of templates, its bad habit to have everything in the parent component, the problem here is not the app structure , the problem is how do I display the selected element to a settings components that is it ,

Comment: Are you want to write all of your templates manually? I mean you can have a table template than you can write all of your templates with for loop.

Comment: can you please demonstrate your solution via codesandbox provided above?

Comment: I think it is what you want : https://codesandbox.io/s/templates-forked-hlhnd?file=/src/Components/Templates.js (I changed settings,app and index . now you can see your selected item under form) I just moved 'selected' and 'setSelected' from templates.js to index.js so now all components can use 'selected' with props . I will give example for data based table templates in few hours.

Comment: here: https://codesandbox.io/s/templates-forked-y3e7m it works. now you can change your data with changeOnData function. I think your problem was using js-dom. you should change and get values with react state not with js-dom.

Comment: Put that as the answer I will accept your answer, very good solution I was overthinking damn , thanks man

Comment: No problem glad I'm could help :)

Comment: Someone deleted my other post that's why I edited this post with your last question's answer.

Comment: I see someone deleted your post whatsoever , can you please show this styling on your codesandbox example? Thanks man for the links and informations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230987/discussion-between-the-dead-man-and-hyper).